# Android print receipt wit image and text

Tags: android, pdf, printing

I need to create a recipt after user registration with following data

with following pattern

```
                           ID              10001

                           Name:            ABC
Photograph
                           Company          XYZ

                           Person to meet   Mr P
```

How i can make print of this particular data and in particular format please help

can it possible to save this data as PDF i mean with photograph also

Please guide me

Thanks in Advance

Pragna

Comment: Where do you get the data from?? how exactly would you like this to be done programmatically or graphically?? when the user registers what other data do you get in the registration form and where do you submit the data??SQLite or Mysql??What have you done so far???we need details in order to help you....

Answer (score 1):

There are several library for creating pdf in android. Some library :

1. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.html
2. http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/
3. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-itext/image.html

Use this library and see the documentation of this for formatting.